# LDAP Authentication fail with javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: java, spring, ldap

We have LDAP login supported application. One of our customer is not able to login in application and in logs we can see exception.

```
16 Aug 2020 04:08:14,220 - DEBUG - Searching for user 'My_User', with user search [ searchFilter: '(&(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person))(sAMAccountName={0}))', searchBase: '', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
    16 Aug 2020 04:08:14,556 - ERROR - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DF, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
    �]; remaining name '/'
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at com.unica.manager.security.filter.PlatformPostDeligationFilter.doFilter(PlatformPostDeligationFilter.java:142)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:231)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at com.unica.manager.security.filter.SuiteDelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(SuiteDelegatingFilterProxy.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.unica.manager.csrf.EMMCsrfFilter.doFilter(EMMCsrfFilter.java:180)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.unica.manager.security.filter.XContentTypeResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(XContentTypeResponseHeaderFilter.java:82)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.unica.manager.security.filter.DirectoryAttackFilter.doFilter(DirectoryAttackFilter.java:44)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3980)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1820)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
    Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DF, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
    �]; remaining name '/'
        at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:228)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:820)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:803)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.searchForUser(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator.authenticate(BindAuthenticator.java:95)
        at com.unica.manager.security.ldap.UnicaLdapBindAuthenticator.authenticate(UnicaLdapBindAuthenticator.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:187)
        ... 76 more
    Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-031007DF, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
    �]; remaining name '/'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3187)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3093)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2900)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1858)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1781)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1798)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:430)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:408)
        at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.search(DelegateContext.java:372)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:308)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntryInternal(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:333)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate$3.executeWithContext(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:318)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:817)
```

They try to login with My_User. But at our local application with same configuration we are able to login smoothly.
I went through [This](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/136560/ldap-configuration-root-context-has-spa.html) according this OU might have space, but in customer's case there is no space in any of the configuration parameter for LDAP mapping.

Also I went through the  [NamingException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html#remainingName)  documentation, in which I have found
*Remaining Name. Portion of name that has not been resolved.*, I didn't get this what exactly here it means.

The only difference between Customer's and our setup is they are using LDAPS(secure), and we are using LDAP(non secure) ... is this make any difference  ?

Can anyone explain about  **SvcErr: DSID-031007DF** what it is all about.

Note - we are using Spring LDAP template

Any pointer to resolve this problem really appreciated.